# syntax to give number dynamically for setting a value to an attribute for a tag element in xml file using minidom python

Tags: python, xml

I'm using python to create tag element inside a xml file. My xml file content is like the following:

```
<timestep time="2.00">
        <vehicle id="myflow.0" x="20.67" y="998.40" angle="90.00" type="car" speed="15.57" pos="20.67" lane="e18_2" slope="0.00" acceleration="1.32"/>
        <vehicle id="myflow.1" x="5.10" y="995.20" angle="90.00" type="car" speed="9.32" pos="5.10" lane="e18_1" slope="0.00" acceleration="0.00"/>
```

I want to add another vehicle tag element but with id="myflow.[i]" and for example each time I create a new vehicle tag element, I want to add one to I like i+1. Now this myflow.[I] causes a syntax error.what I have tried is like the following:

```
          NodeId=0
          f=0
          for f in range(3):
            newVehicle = doc.createElement("vehicle")
            newVehicle.setAttribute("id", myflow.[NodeId])
            NodeId+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

instead of

`newVehicle.setAttribute("id", myflow.[NodeId])`.

use

`newVehicle.setAttribute("id", f'myflow.{NodeId}')`.